# Issue with passing arguments to button onClick js function with Django template

Tags: python, django-templates

I am using django template as standalone.
When using it, the Django template rendering is escaping single-quotes (adding \ to ') for the arguments of onClick function call.

`<button id="order" onclick="myFunction('{{ val }}')"> {{ val }} </button>`

when rendered in python with with `val = 'somevalue'`:

Output:

`<button id="order" onclick="myFunction(\'somevalue\')"> somevalue </button>`

This results in error and the button click does not work.

Expected:
`<button id="order" onclick="myFunction('somevalue')"> somevalue </button>`

With more checking I found that the single-quotes inside double-quotes are escaped by django template rendering.

Is there any way this adding \ to single-quotes inside double-quotes can be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue after some debugging and stepping through the django rendering part.

The issue was, i was using

```
with open('template_file.html') as f:
    htmlString = f.readlines()
    t = Template('htmlString')`
    c = Context({'val': 'someval'})
    result_html = t.render(c)
```

With these steps, when the html file is read, it is converted into python string which will have escaped single quotes (')
This was the problem.

Solution

Change is to use django's loader from django.template

```
template = loader.get_template('template_file.html')
ctxt = {'val':'somevalue'}
result_html = template.render(ctxt)
```

With this above, the output is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this combination and let me know.

`val = "'somestring'"`

```html
<button id="order" onclick="myFunction({{ val }})"> {{ val }} </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.
I tried this way. But the result is like below: `<button id="order" onclick="myFunction(\''somevalue\'')"> somevalue </button>`